# Создание собственного исключения

Tags: java

Класс для обращения к базе данных:

```
public  class StudentDao extends Dao<Student> {
    ResultSet resultSet;
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement select;
    PreparedStatement delete;
    PreparedStatement update;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    PreparedStatement insert;
    public StudentDao()  {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            if(connection==null) {
                connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
                connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();
            }}
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    private PreparedStatement getInsert(){
        if(insert==null){
            try {
                insert= connection.prepareStatement( "insert into student (first_name,second_name) values (?,?);");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return insert;
    }
    private PreparedStatement getSelect(){
        if(select==null){
            try {
                select=connection.prepareStatement("select id, first_name, second_name from student;");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return select;
    }
    private PreparedStatement getUpdate(){
        if(update==null){
            try {
                update=connection.prepareStatement( "Update student set first_name=?,second_name=? where id=?;");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return update;
    }
    private PreparedStatement getDelete(){
        if(delete==null){
            try {
                delete=connection.prepareStatement("delete from student where id=?;");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return delete;
    }
    public void insert(Student obj) {

        try {
            getInsert();
            insert.setString(1, obj.getFirst_name());
            insert.setString(2, obj.getSecond_name());
            insert.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> select() {
        List<Student> students=new LinkedList<>();
        Student student=null;
        try {
            getSelect();
            resultSet=select.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next()){
                student=new Student();
                student.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                student.setFirst_name(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                student.setSecond_name(resultSet.getString("second_name"));
                students.add(student);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(resultSet!=null){
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        for(Student text:students)
        System.out.print(text);
        return students;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Student obj, int id) {
        try {
            getDelete();
            delete.setInt(1,id);
            delete.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void update(Student obj) {
        try {
            getUpdate();
            update.setString(1, obj.getFirst_name());
            update.setString(2, obj.getSecond_name());
            update.setInt(3, obj.getId());
            update.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public  void  closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            if (insert!=null ){
                insert.close();
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            if (select!=null ){
                select.close();
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            if (update!=null ){
                update.close();
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            if (delete!=null ){
                delete.close();
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Получение соединения из файла Properties:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    public Connection getConnection() throws MyException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Connection connection=null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Properties.txt"));

            properties.load(bufferedReader);

            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty("URL"),
            properties.getProperty("USERNAME"), properties.getProperty("PASSWORD"));
            return connection;
        }finally {
            throw new MyException();

        }
    }
}

class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException() {};
    public MyException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    };
}
```

Код стал нерабочим. Выскакивает ошибка MyException.

В чем проблема?

Где, что исправлять?

Comment: А зачем Вы в блоке `finally` бросаете исключение? Это все равно, что сходить в магазин за продуктами, вернуться, и перед тем как поставить пакеты в холодильник резко подбежать к окну и выкинуть в него пакеты с криком `"MyException!"`.

Comment: Возьмите за правило, форматировать код.

Answer (score 2):

Блок `finally` выполняется независимо от того, какие исключения вылетят в блоке `try`. Поэтому `MyException` у Вас всё время и вылетает.

В блоке `finally` обычно выполняют закрытие файлов, `connection`'ов, `statement`'ов и т.д. Поэтому смысл выкидывать там user-defined Exception непонятен. Тем более, сам `MyException`, судя по коду, не несёт никакой смысловой нагрузки. Стандартный `SQLException` и тот информативнее.

В Вашем случае лучше вообще убрать блок `finally`, а после `throws` перечислить необходимые checked-исключения. Например, FileNotFoundException (который может выбросится если файл `"D:\\Properties.txt"` не будет найден). Или же отловить эти checked-исключения в блоке `catch`.

Comment: Просто мне сказано,что нужно создать свое исключение, а не использовать стандартные.

Comment: @user184293, тогда бросай это исключение в блоке `catch`, где ты отлавливаешь cheched-исключения.